# How does Wynn know Jamie's baby is at Tommy Doyle's house?

Tags: plot-explanation, halloween-curse-of-michael-myers

In *Halloween: The Curse of Michael Myers*, Wynn is found sitting in TV 
room with his followers at Tommy Doyle's house where Jamie's baby is there.
Actually, Jamie hid her baby when she died, so Tommy took her baby and is providing shelter to it. But how does Wynn know Jamie's baby is at Tommy Doyle's house?